# Getting the value of a button's data attribute when all buttons have the same id

Tags: jquery

I have a table of buttons that are printed using PHP.  Each button has a different value in its data attribute but does the same thing.  I want the value of the data attribute of a particular button's data attribute.  This does not work:

```
$(this).find('button').data('myatt')
```

The above returns the first button's data attribute value rather than the one the user clicked.

**EDIT:** jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7fkfu/17/

Any ideas?  Thank you :).

Comment: Richard's answer should do it for you. If not, please indicate the context where you are trying to retrieve the data attribute. Where does the (non-working) line of code you showed fit in your code? It wouldn't hurt to show a little of the (generated) HTML too. (And don't have more than one element on the page with the same ID.)

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/7fkfu/17 hope that helps explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the problem is in how you were trying to use the `.on` method: you were trying to say `on().click()`, but you don't want both. The first param to `.on()` is a string indicatingthe event(s) you want to handle. Then a selector, an optional data param, and then last you put the actual handler. (There's also an events-map format - see the [.on() doco](http://api.jquery.com/on/).) Also in the fiddle it was checking for buttons with `[rel=modal]` but in the html it was `rel=test`. Try the following:

```
$(function() {
  $('#mytable').on('click','tr button[rel=test]',function() {
     alert($(this).data('mydata'));
  });
});
```

An updated fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/7fkfu/19/

Also, don't create more than one element with the same ID. (Doesn't affect your code in this case, but really it is invalid HTML and if you actually try to select elements by ID it will matter.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside of the click event for the button then this should work:

```
$(this).data('myatt');
```

Note that you really shouldn't have more than one element on the same page with the same ID!

Comment: Thanks for the help.. doesn't solve my problem :(.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7fkfu/16/

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
$("#yourButtonId").click(function() {
 alert($(this).val());
  //or something else that you want
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry.. doesn't fix it but thanks.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7fkfu/17/comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)